# jdk version 1.7 has been found?

Tags: java, android, installation

Is it normal that this message appears , I have installed JDK 6 and when I'm about to install Android Sdk  it says that , is it normal? or is it because I have installed JDK 6 in D:/ ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

"jdk version 1.7 has been found" may be you have jdk 7? It is not important for android.
You can choose JDK level (by path) to your every  project after installing Android SDK

Comment: No, I'm sure I installed jdk 6 but why does it detect jdk 1.7 when I actually have installed version 6?

Comment: What OS do you have? For example, OS X has jdk without manually installation, sometimes

Comment: windows xp (don't laugh)

Comment: Check C:\Program Files\Java, may be it has jdk directory, doesn't matter from where. After that you can change environment variable JAVA_HOME to your jdk 6 in the D: